# How can I get html tags to render inside a React/Next <head> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I took over a spaghetti code React/Next project.  And there was zero thought put into SEO. And I am not a great react dev. So now I am trying to get tags rendered in the  Component.

```
    <Head>
    <meta
      key="data-test"
      data-name="test root"
    ></meta>
    {data?.headHtml?.metaTags.map((tag: ITag, index: number) => (
      <RenderHead
        key={index}
        {...tag}
      />
    ))}
  </Head>
```

The RenderHead component is pretty straightforward:

```
    type Props = {
      outputType: string;
      output: string;
    };

    function RenderHead(props: Props) {
  console.log(props);
  const outputType: string = props.outputType;
  const output: string = props.output;

  if (outputType == 'title') {
    return <title key="title">{props.output}</title>;
  } else if (outputType == 'desc') {
    return (
      <meta
        key="description"
        name="description"
        content={output}
      ></meta>
    );
  } else if (outputType == 'schema') {
    return (
      <script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.output.replace(/\\/g, '') }}
      ></script>
    );
  }
}

export default RenderHead;
```

The data flowing is from GraphQl is pretty straightforward as well:

```
{
headHtml: {
  MetaTags: [
   {
outputType: 'desc',
output: 'A meta description here'
},
{
outputType: 'title',
output: 'Some title'
}
]
}
}
```

The title tag works but the rest do not show up at all. I have been at this for hours and while the title does output, the description and schema don't render.

How can I get all three to render?

-- Update

Ok after some messing with it, things are working in the if I "View Page Source", but I don't see them if I inspect.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you doing `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: {  __html: props.output } }}`?

Comment: Because the docs say: "and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous." Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Konrad I think you were right. I updated

Answer (score 1):

When I need to add `<title>` or `<meta>` tags in React.js, I exclusively rely on the library available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet-async

Comment: Thanks. I looked at Helmet.  And I may go that way.  But This is an entirely Front end app. No backend.